# How to make snow fall motion for a bitmap in android

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I am making an app in which a bitmap of snow  will fall down.It takes a random position on the screen and fall down to certain distance.I can make the snow fall down to certain distance and disappear there.But i need the snow to appear blurred at the start and gradually appear good and finally appear blurred and disappear during its motion on the screen.(means we know how the snow fall is.In the similar way,users should easily understand starting and ending of the snow fall). Please help me to make the snow motion.

```
import java.util.Random;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation;

public class Leaf { 
    private float x;
    private float rawX;
    private float y;
    private float speedY;
    private int heightBound;
    private Bitmap bitmap;  
    private float bounceOffset;
    private boolean touched;
    private float xOffset,yOffset;
    private int width;
    private int height;
    float angle;
    float randomx,randomy,randomy1;

public Leaf(Bitmap source, int canvasHeight, int canvasWidth){      
    Random rand = new Random();     
    randomx=rand.nextFloat();
    randomy1=rand.nextFloat();

    speedY = 1 + rand.nextFloat() * 3;      
    //float scaleRate = rand.nextFloat() * 0.5f;
    //if(scaleRate <= 0.01){
        //scaleRate = 0.1f;
    //}
    width = (int)(source.getWidth()); //* scaleRate);
    height = (int)(source.getHeight());// * scaleRate);
    bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(source, width, height, true);        
    rawX = rand.nextFloat() * canvasWidth;  
    x = rawX;
    randomy=1+rand.nextFloat()*canvasHeight;
    y = -bitmap.getHeight();        
    heightBound = canvasHeight + bitmap.getHeight();    
    bounceOffset = 8.0f;
    touched = false;
    xOffset = rand.nextFloat();
    if(xOffset >= 1.5){
        xOffset = xOffset - 3;}

    }       


public float getX() {
    return x;
}

public void setX(float x) {
    this.x = x;
}

public float getY() {
    return y;
}

public void setY(float y) {
    this.y = y;
}

public float getSpeedY() {
    return speedY;
}

public void setSpeedY(float speedY) {
    this.speedY = speedY;
}   

public boolean isTouched(){
    return touched;
}

public void setTouched(boolean flag){
    this.touched = flag;
}

public Bitmap getBitmap() {
    return bitmap;
}

public void setBitmap(Bitmap flag) {
    this.bitmap = flag;
}

public void drawLeaf(Canvas canvas, Paint paint){
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.reset();
    matrix.postTranslate(x+2,randomy+2); // Centers image
    matrix.postRotate(angle);
    float px=x+bitmap.getHeight()/2;
    float py=y+bitmap.getWidth()/2;
    matrix.postTranslate(px, py);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, matrix, paint);
    //canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap,x,randomy, paint);


}   

public void handleFalling(boolean fallingDown){
    if(fallingDown){
        this.y += this.speedY;  
        this.x += this.xOffset;

        angle=angle+0.5f;
        if(this.y >= (5*randomy1)+(5*bitmap.getHeight())){
            this.y = -this.bitmap.getHeight();
            this.x = rawX;

        }
    }else{

        this.y -= this.speedY;
        this.x += this.xOffset;
        angle=angle+0.4f;
        if(this.y <= -this.bitmap.getHeight()){
            this.y += 6*this.bitmap.getHeight();
            this.x = rawX;

        }
    }

}

public void handleTouched(float touchX, float touchY){          
    float centerX = this.x + this.bitmap.getWidth() / 2.0f;
    float centerY = this.y + this.bitmap.getHeight() / 2.0f;

    if(centerX <= touchX){
        this.x -= this.bounceOffset;
        if(centerY <= touchY){
            this.y -= this.bounceOffset;
        }else{
            this.y += this.bounceOffset;
        }

    }else{
        this.x += this.bounceOffset;
        if(centerY <= touchY){
            this.y -= this.bounceOffset;
        }else{
            this.y += this.bounceOffset;
        }
    }

    this.bounceOffset *= 0.9;
    if(this.bounceOffset < 1.0){
        this.bounceOffset = 8.0f;
        touched = false;

        }   

    }

}
```

Here leaf means snow.This class is for making the leaf falldown in handlefalling method().and drawleaf() is for making the leaf translate using matrix.

Comment: ok, but help with what ?

Comment: May be this one http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-live-wallpapers-on-android--mobile-9516

Comment: What code do you have so far? If we could see it we might be able to offer better suggestions.

Comment: if you use Bitmap.createScaledBitmap there is a long way before you get a good result...